# Original paper on the augmented Lagrangian method in FEM

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

I am writing a paper in which I want to cite the earliest reference to the augmented Lagrangian method in FEM. For the pure Lagrangian method in FEM, the classical work of Babuška [1] is the original paper, but I cannot find it for the augmented Lagrangian technique.

[1] Babuška, I. [The finite element method with Lagrangian multipliers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01436561). Numerische Mathematik, 20(3):179–192, 1973.

Comment: Well, if you haven't seen the reference before it means it has not influenced your work, why citing it?

Comment: In fact, it's a PhD thesis and the review chapter compares several constraint enforcement methods (Lagrange multiplier, augmented Lagrange multiplier, penalty, Nitsche, etc.) in FEM. For the other methods I could find the original references; I thought it would be nice if I could also do it for the augmented Lagrangian method).

Comment: Have you checked the following? (1) Glowinski, Roland, and A. Marroco. "Sur l'approximation, par éléments finis d'ordre un, et la résolution, par pénalisation-dualité d'une classe de problèmes de Dirichlet non linéaires." ESAIM: Mathematical Modelling and Numerical Analysis-Modélisation Mathématique et Analyse Numérique 9.R2 (1975): 41-76.

(2) Gabay, Daniel, and Bertrand Mercier. A dual algorithm for the solution of non linear variational problems via finite element approximation. Institut de recherche d'informatique et d'automatique, 1975.

Comment: Neither of them. I will check them in the upcoming days and tell my opinion. Thanks for the references.

Comment: @nicoguaro The first reference, from Glowinski, is the one I need. If you write it to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the following two references:

1. Glowinski, Roland, and A. Marroco. [Sur l'approximation, par éléments finis d'ordre un, et la résolution, par pénalisation-dualité d'une classe de problèmes de Dirichlet non linéaires.](http://www.numdam.org/article/M2AN_1975__9_2_41_0.pdf) ESAIM: Mathematical Modelling and Numerical Analysis-Modélisation Mathématique et Analyse Numérique 9.R2 (1975): 41-76.
2. Gabay, Daniel, and Bertrand Mercier. [A dual algorithm for the solution of non linear variational problems via finite element approximation.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122176900031) Institut de recherche d'informatique et d'automatique, 1975.

After the OP reviewed the references it appears that 1. Glowinski and Marroco 1975 is the first one discussing the topic.